# Functional equation $ f(x+yf(x^2))=f(x)+xf(xy) $

Tags: functional-equations

I have trouble solving the following functional equation: $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+yf(x^2))=f(x)+xf(xy)$.

I think $f(x)=x$ is the unique solution, especially, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. But how do we show that?

Comment: Would it help to use $f(x)=x+g(x)$ and maybe find a way to determine that $g$ must be identically zero?

Comment: @Tucker: Sure. How do you go about doing it?

Comment: Note that $ f ( x ) = 0 $ is another solution.

Comment: Try using $y=x$ in the functional equation. Does it lead anywhere?

Comment: It's been [discussed on AoPS also](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1649091)

Comment: Hans, please improve your Question by adding some context, e.g. where did you encounter this problem?  As is it will likely be closed for lack of context, and you've been on the site for several years, so this should not be a surprise to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beginning steps are the same as in the answer of @MohsenShahriari, which I repeat for sake of completeness.

---

Our equation is $$f(x + yf(x^2)) = f(x) + xf(xy).\tag 0$$

Setting $y = 0$ in $(0)$, we get $xf(0) = 0$. Setting again $x = 1$ gives us $f(0) = 0$.

Setting $x = 1$ in $(0)$, we get $$f(1 + yf(1)) = f(1) + f(y).\tag 1$$

If $f(1) \neq 1$, then we may set $y = \frac{1}{1 - f(1)}$ in $(1)$ and get $f(1) = 0$. Then $(1)$ implies that $f(y) = 0$ for all $y\in \Bbb R$, which is one solution to the equation.

Now assume that $f(1) = 1$. Then $(1)$ becomes $$f(1 + y) = 1 + f(y).\tag 2$$

Using induction with $(2)$ gives $$f(n + y) = n + f(y), \forall n\in \Bbb Z_{> 0}.\tag 3$$

Setting $y = y - n$ in $(3)$, we get $f(-n + y) = -n + f(y), \forall n \in \Bbb Z_{> 0}$. Combined with $(3)$, we have $$f(n + y) = n + f(y), \forall n\in \Bbb Z.\tag 4$$

Setting $y = 0$ in $(4)$, we get $f(n) = n, \forall n \in \Bbb Z$.

For integer $n \neq 0$, setting $x = n$ and $y = \frac y n$ in $(0)$ gives $n + f(ny) = n + nf(y)$, hence we get $f(ny) = nf(y)$. In particular, for every rational number $q = \frac u v$ with $u, v \in \Bbb Z$, setting $y = q$ and $n = v$ gives $f(q) = q$.

Setting $x = -x$ in $(0)$, we get $$f(-x + y f(x^2)) = f(-x) - xf(-xy) = -f(x) + xf(xy).\tag 5$$

Taking difference of $(0)$ and $(5)$, we get $$f(x + yf(x^2)) - f(-x + yf(x^2)) = 2f(x).\tag 6$$

Now for any $t\neq 0$, we have $f(t^2)\neq 0$, otherwise setting $x = t$ and $y = \frac 1 t$ in $(0)$ would give $f(1) = 0$, contradicting our hypothesis.

Therefore, if $x\neq 0$, then we may set $y = \frac{x + y}{f(x^2)}$ in $(6)$ and get $f(2x + y) - f(y) = 2f(x) = f(2x)$. Setting again $x = \frac x 2$, we get $$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y).\tag 7$$

Using $(7)$, we may rewrite $(0)$ and get $$f(yf(x^2)) = xf(xy).\tag 8$$

Setting $y = x$ in $(8)$, we get $f(xf(x^2)) = xf(x^2)$.

Setting $y = f(x^2)$ in $(8)$, we get $f(f(x^2)^2) = xf(xf(x^2)) = x^2f(x^2)$. Since $x^2$ can be any non-negative real number, we have $$f(f(x)^2) = xf(x), \forall x \geq 0. \tag 9$$

Setting $x = -x$ in $(9)$, we get $f(f(x)^2) = xf(x), \forall x \leq 0$. Combined with $(9)$, we get $f(f(x)^2) = xf(x), \forall x$.

Setting $x = f(x)$ in $(8)$, we get $f(yf(f(x)^2)) = f(x)f(f(x)y)$, hence $f(xyf(x)) = f(x)f(yf(x))$. When $f(x) \neq 0$, setting again $y = \frac y {f(x)}$ gives $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$.

When $f(x) = 0$, we note that $f(x + 1) = f(x) + f(1) = 1 \neq 0$, hence we have $f((x + 1)y) = f(x + 1) f(y)$, which again leads to $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$. Therefore we have $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x, y$.

It follows that $f$ is an increasing function. In fact, for any $x \geq 0$, we have $f(x) = f(\sqrt x)^2 \geq 0$. Hence whenever $x \geq y$, we have $f(x) - f(y) = f(x - y) \geq 0$.

Since we already know $f(q) = q$ for any rational number $q$, this implies $f(x) = x$ for any real number $x$.

Otherwise, assume there is $x$ such that $f(x) \neq x$. Replacing $x$ with $-x$ if necessary, we may assume that $f(x) > x$. Then there is a rational number $q$ such that $f(x) > q > x$. But since $f$ is increasing, $q > x$ implies $q = f(q) > f(x)$, contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

You can show that the only continuous solutions to the functional equation
$$ f \Big( x + y f \big( x ^ 2 \big) \Big) = f ( x ) + x f ( x y ) \tag 0 \label 0 $$
are the constant zero function and the identity function. It's easy to see that these two are solutions. To show that they are the only ones, first let $ y = 0 $ in \eqref{0} to get $ f ( 0 ) = 0 $. Now, assuming $ f ( 1 ) \ne 1 $, you can let $ x = 1 $ and $ y = \frac 1 { 1 - f ( 1 ) } $ in \eqref{0} which leads to $ f ( 1 ) = 0 $. Thus, we must either have $ f ( 1 ) = 0 $ or $ f ( 1 ) = 1 $. In the case that $ f ( 1 ) = 0 $, you can let $ x = 1 $ in \eqref{0} and conclude that $ f $ is the constant zero function. From now on, we assume that $ f ( 1 ) = 1 $. Letting $ x = 1 $ in \eqref{0}, you get $ f ( y + 1 ) = f ( y ) + 1 $. Substituting $ y - 1 $ for $ y $ in this equation, we get $ f ( y - 1 ) = f ( y ) - 1 $. Using the last two equations, we inductively get
$$ f ( x + n ) = f ( x ) + n \tag 1 \label 1 $$
for each integer $ n $. In particular, this shows that $ f ( n ) = n $ for any integer $ n $. Thus, if for some integer $ n $ we let $ x = n $ in \eqref{0}, we'll have
$ f \big( n ^ 2 y \big) = n f ( n y ) $. Letting $ y = \frac m { n ^ 2 } $, where $ m $ and $ n $ are integers with $ n \ne 0 $, we get
$$ f \Big( \frac m n \Big) = \frac m n \text . \tag 2 \label 2 $$
Since the set of rational numbers is dense in the set of real numbers, if $ f $ is continuous, then by \eqref{2} we can show that $ f $ is the identity function.

Comment: Without assuming continuity, you can generalize \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} to $ f ( \alpha x + \beta ) = \alpha f ( x ) + \beta $, for rational $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $. You can also generalize this so that $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ can be square roots of rational numbers, or square roots of square roots of rational numbers, or ... . But I can't see these observations leading us anywhere closer to showing $ f $ is the identity function, or, as you've asked, $ f $ is additive.

Comment: Brilliant, this is an amazing solution